# Display combined form for two models in FormWizard step

Tags: django, django-forms, formwizard

I have User, Profile, PhysParams models.
Profile and PhysParams have OneToOne relationship to User.

I'm trying to display forms for these two above related to logged in user.

I've came upon FormSet, ModelFormSet and InlineFormSet but I'm not sure which one to use.

Trying

```
JoinedFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, Profile, PhysicalParams)
```

produces

```
KeyError at /registration_form/ u'__module__' Request Method:   GET
Request URL:    http://hostname:8000/registration_form/ Django
Version:    1.5 Exception Type: KeyError Exception Value:    u'__module__'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create them and render them as individual forms on the UI.

And you need to pass the request.POST into each of those forms, so they take their respective fields and you can validate and save them all.